# Yet more Errors Thrown by Php

Tags: php

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    #Email Msg Details
    $emailSendTo = "myemail@email.com";
    $emailSubj = "New Professor / Course Suggestion";
    $selected_radio = $_POST['addType'];
    $course_prof_name = $_POST['name']= trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['name'])));
    $select_dep = $_POST['deptName']= trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['deptName'])));
    $email = $_POST['email']= trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['email'])));


/* I can't remember if it should be '' or NULL, but some simple testing will let you know which it is*/
    if(($_POST['addType']) != NULL){
         if(($_POST['name']) != NULL){
            if(($_POST['deptName']) != NULL){
                if(($_POST['email']) != NULL){
                    $selected_radio = $_POST['addType'];
                    if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $emailSendTo)) { 
                        return; 
                    } 
                    else { 
                        echo "<span color='red;'>Invalid email address.</span>"; 
                    } 
                }
                else{
                    echo "<span color='red;'>Oops need an email address.</span>";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "<span color='red;'>Oops need a department.</span>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<span color='red;'>Oops need a name.</span>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<span color='red;'>Please select a radio option.</span>";
    }
}
    $email_message .= "Suggestion Type: ".$selected_radio."\n";
    $email_message .= "Suggestion Name: ".$course_prof_name."\n";
    $email_message .= "Department: ".$select_dep."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".$email."\n";   

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: Anonymous User '."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($emailSendTo, $emailSubj, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

What does 
Notice: Undefined index: addType in C:\xampp\htdocs\urd\add_p_c.php on line 13
Please select a radio option.
Notice: Undefined variable: email_message in C:\xampp\htdocs\urd\add_p_c.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined variable: email_from in C:\xampp\htdocs\urd\add_p_c.php on line 48

Mean?

Comment: Where are you defining `string`?

Comment: From what you posted I don't see "$string" ever being assigned, or clean_string() defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignments are correct but there doesn't exist a variable, `$string`(in which you reference in line 6, 7, etc etc). This is why it is complaining about the undefined variable, string.

And for line 11, you want:

```
if(isset($_POST['var']))
```

And for the undefined method, you haven't defined the method yet(or atleast in a place that can be called from line 39).

Comment: How do I go about fixing this? Bit confused what I was even doing with $string in the first place. Would be appreciated :)

Comment: It seems like you want to do something like `addslashes($_POST['name'])` etc, rather than `$string`

Comment: This worked, but still throwing: `Notice: Undefined index: addType in C:\xampp\htdocs\urd\add_p_c.php on line 11` AND
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function clean_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\urd\add_p_c.php on line 39`

Comment: Well, you need to make sure it exists by doing `isset($_POST['addType'])`. And you still don't have clean_string defined, you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that $string is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any definition for $string anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

@user700070: Change

```
$course_prof_name = $_POST['name']= trim(strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
$select_dep = $_POST['deptName']= trim(strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
$email = $_POST['email']= trim(strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
```

to

```
$course_prof_name = $_POST['name'];
$select_dep = $_POST['deptName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Your HTML (the sample I saw before you edited your post and removed it) should also change from

```
Professor<input type='radio' name='addType' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type='radio' name='addType' />
```

to

```
Professor<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Professor" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Course" />
```

otherwise `addType` will always be empty.

Comment: @user700070: Please post your changes as a clearly marked edit to your question, rather than replacing someone's answer.  (Like, tack "UPDATE:" and the updated code and problem on to the end of your question.)